# mobile responsive form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

On my mobile responsive website Registration page, The registration form is moved from its original position on PC to a different position on Phone/Mobile deviece.. The re positioned form does not work (I cant input in value or text)

(Works fine on iphone 5 and other phones excluding chrome on Iphone 6)

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 if ($(window).width() <= 767){ 
  $('#side-content').insertAfter('#mobilePos').css;
 } else {
  $('#side-content').insertAfter('#desktopPos').css;
 }
});
$(window).resize(function(){
 if ($(window).width() <= 767){ 
  $('#side-content').insertAfter('#mobilePos').css;
 } else {
  $('#side-content').insertAfter('#desktopPos').css;
 }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to move the form. So just put it with this code.

$('#side-content').insertAfter('#mobilePos');

Css function only to style element with jquery.

CMIIW.

Comment: couple you please explain better or.. just put here what i should replace current code with.. I CAN COPY PASTE

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 767){  
      $('#side-content').insertAfter('#mobilePos');
    } else {
      $('#side-content').insertAfter('#desktopPos');
    }
  });
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 767){  
      $('#side-content').insertAfter('#mobilePos');
    } else {
      $('#side-content').insertAfter('#desktopPos');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks But same thing happens as the first code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Use Css Media Query

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
     User Css Code For min - desktop Screen resolution
 }



 @media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
     User Css Code For Tab Screen resolution
 }
```

Same for mobile screen and you want any ohter screen like smart tv & more ..

Comment: hi... i have no idea what to do with this... can you kindly guide me with the steps please.

Comment: Read  [Responsive Web Design - Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)